# Access view exposed filter arguments in field view

Tags: 7, views

My problem is that I can't access `$view->filter['my_filter_field']` from my `views-view-fields.tpl.php` file.

In `views-view.tpl.php` I get my correct View object with the arguments sent via AJAX as exposed filter parameters, but how can I get this information without using the field's template file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use object methods (functions) to get and set exposed filter inputs.

E.g.

Use `$views->get_input_filter` and `$views->set_input_filter($filters)`.  The format for filters is as follows:

```
$filters = array(
  'identifier' => '[your ident name]', 
  'value' => '[your value']
);
```

Comment: Where can I find these methods? I was searching through whole View module (version 7.x-3.3) and did't found anything.

Comment: In the Views API: http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/class/view/7

Comment: OK, it works but get_exposed_input still return previous view, not view for new selected value (in exposed filters).

Comment: As I see get_exposed_input() get value from $_GET. I already have this value. My problem is that I can't get into exposed filter variable when changing something on exposed filter and send form. On server this variable is still set to previous value.

Comment: OK, so I found that problem is $_GET variable. I need to pass this variable to exposed filter from other page. After this all my exposed filter submits goes with this $_GET variable, even if I set manually other value to that variable in exposed filter.